# How to fix blur of text because of selectpicker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use selectpicker js plugin for live search select in my project.
This is it: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

But then I got blur text, not only in option but even in search field!
Screenshot here: https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/d4/23/5cd423ae07866237493996.png

I know, the problem appear because of css rule - translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px);

But I absolutely cant find where exactly plugin set this rule, not in css file, and not in js file.
Maybe someone already had this problem, and solved it,I will  very grateful for solution. Or, if it cant be helped, advice me please another one plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`?

Or you could try adding `perspective(1px)` before the 3D translation, like this : `perspective(1px) translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px)`.

Try it in inspector first, and if it works you can either overwrite the existing CSS with your rules, or - I suspect - the plugin might be setting the CSS translation dynamically in Javascript, so you could try searching the .js code for the term "translate3d".

Comment: I was searching translate3d, and didnt found i-i  And sure,  I did it via Ctrl+F (: